# StringTokenizer not making tokens with new lines

Tags: java, number-formatting, stringtokenizer

I am having trouble making a StringTokenizer break up a few lines of text into separate tokens. The inputted text is

```
3
monkeys
```

But, the StringTokenizer is apparently interpreting this as "3monkeys". I need it to be "3" and "monkeys". Because of this, a NumberFormatException is being throw since I need to convert the string "3" into an integer.

This is the code I have so far.

```
    Scanner f = new Scanner( new FileInputStream("input.txt" )); // Yes, i have the actual input file path here, but I changed it for this question.
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt")));

    String temp = "";
    //String cString = "";

    while( f.hasNextLine() ) {
        String cString = f.nextLine();
        temp += cString;
    }
    StringTokenizer everythingTokens = new StringTokenizer( temp );
    String[] everything = new String[ everythingTokens.countTokens() ];

    for( int i = 0; i < everything.length; i++ ) {
        everything[ i ] = everythingTokens.nextToken();
    }

    int numberOfPeople = Integer.parseInt( everything[ 0 ] ); // Line where exception occurs.
    out.println( everything[ 0 ] );
```

The error message is this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3monkeys"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at gift1.main(gift1.java:32)
Java Result: 1
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're appending each line to a string via `temp += cString`, what you have is "3" + "monkeys", which is "3monkeys". You can solve this by adding a space after each line; `temp += cString + " "`.

Answer (score 1):

> StringTokenizer not making tokens with new lines

There are no newline chars in the resulting `String`.  To change that..

```
String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
...
  temp += cString + eol;
```

Ultimately, I would scrap that code and start again.

1. Use `StringBuilder` rather than `String +=`
2. But then, why add the first line into a `String` at all if it is expected to be an integer?  Parse it immediately and thereafter ignore the `String` that was read for the 1st line.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer as it works cross-platform and is a clean way.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is you concatenate 3 and monkeys with these

```
while( f.hasNextLine() ) {
    String cString = f.nextLine();
    temp += cString;
}
```

so temp now will contain 3monkeys you are removing the new line character

if you format your input file such that each line is a separate token then I don't think you still even need the tokenizer there you just have to add cString to the array or better yet use ArrayList so that you won't have to mind the size of the array